# Fetch request not working, works in Postman

Tags: javascript, reactjs, request, fetch

I'm trying to fetch products from created API, but it always fails, here is the call:

```
   export const getProducts = () => dispatch => {
  dispatch({ 
    type: GET_PRODUCTS
  })
  fetch(API_URL+'/products')
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((data) => dispatch({
      type: GET_PRODUCTS_SUCCESS,
      payload: data
    }))
    .catch((err) => dispatch({
      type: GET_PRODUCTS_FAILED,
      payload: err
    }))
}
```

If I go to `localhost:3000/api/products` it works, I see json code. I tried adding headers, tried with Axios, neither works. I read similar questions here but nothing helps..

[image]

Comment: What do you  see in the network tab of developer console (F12)

Comment: What do you mean by `neither works`?

Comment: Where you use the returned data? I mean its react, so maybe the code is correct, but the way you trying to use returned data is invalid. try to `console.log` the `data`, inside `then`, you should see the data, if so, looking for problem in another places

Comment: Post edited, I mean neither of these two solutions helped me, @MattWay

Comment: please post your postman request...

Comment: do you have ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN flag enabled on your Api

Comment: I have `app.use(cors())`. Is that enough ?

Comment: Just solved, I had to added options to request: no-cors, application/json and method..Thank you :)

Comment: This could be because you're running it on localhost. Try allowing cross origin at the backend.